# Meaning of parent of a window

Tags: parent

In 12th Std. computer textbook, gseb (Page no. 28) it is mentioned "If the current window doesn't have a parent, it is treated as a target="self". What is meant by parent of a window? I tried searching on Google but didn't get a satisfactory result. I think the answer to this question would be helpful to not only me, but many students studying in std. 12 gseb.

Comment: No one knows what you're talking about. What programing language? What OS? What widget toolkit? We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

What is meant by *parent of window* is `window.parent`. So the text says if `window` is not encapsulated in a set of frames then `window.parent` is strictly equal to `window`.